# How to get counts for null, not null, distinct values, all rows for all columns in a sql table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently looking to get a table that gets counts for null, not null, distinct values, and all rows for all columns in a given table.  This happens to be in Databricks (Apache Spark).

Something that looks like what is shown below.

[image]

I know I can do this with something like the SQL shown below.  Also, I can use something like Java or Python, etc., to generate the SQL.

The question is:

- Is this the most efficient approach?
- Is there a better way to write this query (less typing and/or more efficient)?

```sql
select 
  1 col_position,
  'location_id' col_name,
  count(*) all_records,
  count(location_id) not_null,
  count(*) - count(location_id) null,
  count(distinct location_id) distinct_values
from
  admin
  
union
select 
  2 col_position,
  'location_zip' col_name,
  count(*) all_records,
  count(location_zip) not_null,
  count(*) - count(location_zip) null,
  count(distinct location_zip) distinct_values
from
  admin
  
union
select 
  3 col_position,
  'provider_npi' col_name,
  count(*) all_records,
  count(provider_npi) not_null,
  count(*) - count(provider_npi) null,
  count(distinct provider_npi) distinct_values
from
  admin
  
order by col_position
;
```

Comment: Use `union all`.  This should be pretty efficient, unless you put the values in separate columns.

Comment: If you're using python, you might want to consider loading the entire table into a dataframe and counting there; it could potentially be faster and would definitely be simpler code. Other than that, the only real optimisation you can make to what you have is to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` so that the query engine doesn't have to waste time looking for duplicate rows.

Comment: if you write Python code then you can cache count(*) and reuse it. Also you can cache "admin" table if it is small.

Comment: I did go ahead and write some Java code that uses the above query style to get the data and create a meta data table in a meta data schema for each of the tables in the schema of interest.  It only took about half an hour to write. The queries are fairly snappy and only need to run once each time the underlying data are updated. Querying the generated meta data tables is (obviously) very snappy.  Still, it would be nice if something like this was built into the database engine (along the lines of enhancing the table statistics and analyze table functionality). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, using `UNION ALL` should be efficient.

#### Using SQL

To avoid taping all the columns and sub queries, you can generate the SQL query from the list of columns like this:

```scala
val df = spark.sql("select * from admin")

// generate the same query from the columns list
val sqlQuery =
  df.columns.zipWithIndex.map { case (c, i) =>
    Seq(
      s"$i col_position",
      s"$c col_name",
      "count(*) all_records",
      s"count($c) not_null",
      s"count(*) - count($c) null",
      s"count(distinct $c) distinct_values"
    ).mkString("select ", ", ", " from admin")
  }.mkString("", " union all\n", "order by col_position")

spark.sql(sqlQuery).show
```

#### Using DataFrame (Scala)

There are some optimizations you can do by using DataFrame, like calculate `count(*)` one time, avoid typing all the column names, and the possibility to use caching.

Example input DataFrame :

```scala
//+---+---------+--------+---------------------+------+
//|id |firstName|lastName|email                |salary|
//+---+---------+--------+---------------------+------+
//|1  |michael  |armbrust|no-reply@berkeley.edu|100K  |
//|2  |xiangrui |meng    |no-reply@stanford.edu|120K  |
//|3  |matei    |null    |no-reply@waterloo.edu|140K  |
//|4  |null     |wendell |null                 |160K  |
//|5  |michael  |jackson |no-reply@neverla.nd  |null  |
//+---+---------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

First, get count and column list :

```scala
val cols = df.columns
val allRecords = df.count
```

Then, calculate each metric by looping through the columns list (you can create a function for each metric for example) :

```scala
val nullsCountDF = df.select(
  (Seq(expr("'nulls' as metric")) ++ cols.map(c =>
    sum(when(col(c).isNull, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).as(c)
  )): _*
)
val distinctCountDF = df.select(
  (Seq(expr("'distinct_values' as metric")) ++ cols.map(c =>
    countDistinct(c).as(c)
  )): _*
)
val maxDF = df.select(
  (Seq(expr("'max_value' as metric")) ++ cols.map(c => max(c).as(c))): _*
)
val minDF = df.select(
  (Seq(expr("'min_value' as metric")) ++ cols.map(c => min(c).as(c))): _*
)

val allRecordsDF = spark.sql("select 'all_records' as metric," + cols.map(c => s"$allRecords as $c").mkString(","))
```

Finally, union the data frames created above:

```scala
val metricsDF = Seq(allRecordsDF, nullsCountDF, distinctCountDF, maxDF, minDF).reduce(_ union _)

metricsDF.show

//+---------------+---+---------+--------+---------------------+------+
//|metric         |id |firstName|lastName|email                |salary|
//+---------------+---+---------+--------+---------------------+------+
//|all_records    |5  |5        |5       |5                    |5     |
//|nulls          |0  |1        |1       |1                    |1     |
//|distinct_values|5  |3        |4       |4                    |4     |
//|max_value      |5  |xiangrui |wendell |no-reply@waterloo.edu|160K  |
//|min_value      |1  |matei    |armbrust|no-reply@berkeley.edu|100K  |
//+---------------+---+---------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

#### Using DataFrame (Python)

For Python example, you can see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59314024/1386551).

Answer (score 0):

use `count (ifnull(field,0)) total_count`.  This will count all non-null rows.